# Yii REST POST is not working in POSTMAN but in Framework

Tags: rest, post, yii, parameters, postman

how could i post the form to the rest api action. Or how can i test the rest api for creating a record in the db with all the field values. Should we add create aq queryStringUrl. if its comming from a POST form action its fine. But this yii rest api should also work when called on a android device.   I have used $_Request on post of the form , will the same work else where.      if i wanna test the same in POSTMAN how can i do it.                                                                                  http://localhost/basic/web/site/create?fname=deepika&uname=deeps&email=deep@gmail.com&pwd=deepika&pwd_confirm=deepika&gender=female   says 404 in postman. But works in the yii controller url                                 This is the action i have created.
    public function actionCreate()
    {

```
  $params=$_REQUEST;
  //echo $params;
   $model= new UsersForm();

  if(isset($params['fname']))
    $fname=$params['fname'];


  if(isset($params['uname']))
    $uname=$params['uname'];

   if(isset($params['email']))
    $email=$params['email'];

   if(isset($params['pwd']))
    $pwd=$params['pwd'];

   if(isset($params['gender']))
    $gender=$params['gender'];

  if($fname == "" || $uname == "" || $email == "" || $pwd == "" || $gender == ""){
          $this->setHeader(400);
           echo "<pre>".json_encode(array('status'=>0,'error_code'=>400,'errors'=>"Something went wrong"),JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)."</pre>";
  }else{
          $model->fname = $fname;
          $model->uname =  $uname;
          $model->email = $email;
          $model->pwd =  $pwd;
          $model->pwd_confirm =  $pwd;
          $model->gender = $gender;

          if($model->save()){
              if($model->status == 0){
                  $mailSent = Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
                            ->setFrom("noreply@gmail.com")
                            ->setTo($model->email)
                            ->setSubject("Proceed by Verification")
                            ->setTextBody('Plain text content')
                            ->setHtmlBody('<b>HTML content</b>')
                            ->send();
                           // VarDumper::dump($mailSent, 10, true);die();
            }      
              $this->setHeader(200);
             echo "<pre>".json_encode(array('status'=>1,'success_code' => 200,'verification_mail'=>$mailSent,'message'=>'Registered Successfully'),JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)."</pre>";
          }else{
                $this->setHeader(400);
                 echo "<pre>".json_encode(array('status'=>0,'error_code'=>400,'errors'=>$model->errors),JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)."</pre>";
          }
  }
```

// VarDumper::dump($params, 10, true);die();

```
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without code examples its hard to say what goes wrong in your app. I think first of all if you creat new item by GET method, its not REST. In REST API cretion of new item goes by POST method (I say nothing about URL appearance).  When I was realized REST in some project, I create simple methods at the backend application and then on frontend (JavaScript app) create simple method for send request to API URLs, and when I preparing headers to send, and then depending of url I set method to headers GET, POST, or PUT (no DELETE because we not deletin items throgh API). So it may be little bit confusing...  But I believe when you will get things about REST you will resolve your problem.

Comment: Ift creation of new items is through POST than GET. how will the android API implementers call the api solely with their own form fields. should they use the same name as i am tsting in the action. using isset().  Pls note im using yii2.  and how is that i test if all the specific parametrs are passed to it.   Excuse if its the silliest of a question. Thanks. I have added the example action.